# Trying to run node but getting: "librosconsole.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the title says I'm trying to run my node either with rosrun, roslaunch or running the output file directly, but I'm getting this error. When using ldd on the output file it lists librosconsole.so as well as the correct folder where it is located. The LD_LIBRARY_PATH does contain the adress of the folder where it is contained as well.

What is causing this and how to fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337638/trying-to-run-node-but-getting:-%22librosconsole.so:-cannot-open-shared-object-file:-no-such-file-or-directory%22/) by [Zantox](https://answers.ros.org/users/49369/zantox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2019-11-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was that the ROS environment variables (the 'source setup.bash' things) wasn't loaded on the root user, so when I was running the package with sudo it couldn't find ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Zantox](https://answers.ros.org/users/49369/zantox/) with karma: 36 on 2019-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1